# I want to pass List<> from Activity A to B

Tags: android, list, android-intent

I set a class named "Contact", Contact class contains Getters and Setters.
In main Activity.

```
List<Contact> contactList;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

}

private class GetContacts extends AsyncTask<String, String, List<Contact>>{

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

        // 
    }
    @Override
    protected List<Contacts> doInBackground(String... params) {
        // executing some tasks;
        return contactList;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<Contact> result) {
        contactList = result;

    }
```

Now I want to send contactList to another activity.

Comment: do you want to setadapter?

Answer (score 1):

```
putParcelableArrayListExtra(String keyValue, ArrayList< ? extends Parcelable);
```

Use above method from the Intent class.
Note: The custom class(?) must be implements Parcelable interface class.

Answer (score 1):

your Contact.java class

```
public class GymItem implements Serializable{
}
```

MainActivity.class

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                    OtherActivity.class);
Bundle bundleObject = new Bundle();
bundleObject.putSerializable("KEY", contactList);
intent.putExtras(bundleObject);
startActivity(intent);
```

OtherActivity.java

```
ArrayList<Contact> contactList = new ArrayList<Contact>();

Bundle bundleObject = getIntent().getExtras();
contactList = (ArrayList<Contact>) bundleObject
            .getSerializable("KEY");
```

Answer (score 1):

> class A extends Activity{
>
> ```
> List<Contact> contactList;  //your contact list
>
> Intent AtoB = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),B.class);
> AtoB.putParcelableArrayListExtra("Contacts",contactList);
> startActivity(AtoB);
> ```
>
> }
>
> ```
> class Contact implements Parcelable{
> private String name;
> private String phoneNo;
>
> @Override
> public int describeContents() {
>     return 0;
> }
>
> @Override
> public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
>     dest.writeString(name);
>     dest.writeString(phoneNo);
>
> }
> public Contact(){
>
> }
>
> private Contact(Parcel in) {
>     name = in.readString();
>     phoneNo = in.readString();
>
>
> }
>
> public static final Parcelable.Creator<Contact> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<Contact>() {
>
>
>     public Contact[] newArray(int size) {
>         return new Contact[size];
>     }
>     public ContactcreateFromParcel(Parcel in) {
>         // TODO Auto-generated method stub
>         return new Contact(in);
>     }
>
> }; 
> }
>
>  class B extends Activity{
>
>  ArrayList<Contact> listfromA = 
>  getIntent().getParcelableExtra("Contacts"); 
>   }
> ```